# Accessing Android SharedPreferences using generic method

Tags: java, android, generics, enums, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to define a generic wrapper method for Android's SharedPreferences, for getting\setting in a more convenient way a list of predefined parameters.

Initially I defined an enum of all supported types (String, Int & Bool in my case), each one of them is associated with its corresponding class:

```
public enum ParamType {

    String(String.class),
    Int(Intent.class),
    Bool(Boolean.class);

    private final Class paramClass;
    ParamType(Class paramClass) {
        this.paramClass = paramClass;
    }
}
```

Then I defined the enum of the known parameters I use, with the associated type of each one:

```
public enum Param {

    FirstParam(ParamType.Bool),
    SecondParam(ParamType.String),
    ThirdParam(ParamType.Int);

    Param(ParamType paramType) {
        this.paramType = paramType;
    }

    private final ParamType paramType;

}
```

Then I want to have a generic method, that by the given parameter, will know to return the appropriate type:

```
public static <T> T getParamValue(Param param) {

}
```

However, I'm not sure how to implement this method and if it's actually possible, since the generic T param is not passed in the signature above.

Answer (score 0):

It is a OVERENGINEERING, don't do that. You can create interface for saving your customobject and loading it and implement it for SharedPreferences and database. But it is not neccessary to create generic for every integral type, if there is three - five types.

Comment: Well, in my app I have MANY parameters I save on SharedPreferences, and I'm trying to find a better approach to the not-so-nice code of defining string constant for each one, then define explicit setter & getter for each one, and also makes it easier to add new params

Comment: In that case try to use realm database for saving parameters and another features in the app. You can crate class, and save/ load it without any keys, and, most importaintly, can save database file on any place in phone memory and manage your setings by copying files. Drawback is that realm increases size of your app.

Comment: I used that approach for saving sensor readings, maybe for simple application settings it is a overkill

Comment: Ok, thanks for the suggestion, I'll check this option.